# Regex VS DOM : что быстрее?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, dom, парсер

Что будет быстрее работать(DOM или REGEX) при получении значений из определённой HTML страницы?

Так как не секрет что регулярки медленно работают с огронымным строками и хочется найти альтернативу.

Comment: Regex скорее, только не гарантирует правильный результат. ([Обязательная ссылка.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)) Если вам пофиг на результат, берите Regex. Если нет, DOM лучше. Но правильный выход — использовать API, которое предоставляет сайт.

Comment: @VladD, _"Regex ... не гарантирует правильный результат"_ - для языков с расширенным синтаксисом регулярных выражений это утверждение заведомо неверно. Правда, там уже и не факт, что он быстрее. Для всех остальных оно тоже под вопросом. Даже если нельзя выстроить сопоставление закрывающих тегов открывающим, найти некоторый по счёту абзац можно с гарантированной точностью. Правда, опять же это будет весьма хитрая конструкция, которую вряд ли кто-то будет составлять без необходимости.

Comment: @Qwertiy: О, дежа вю :) Ну да, правильный парсер HTML на регулярках _возможен_. Вот он: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994. Вот всего лишь некоторые из причин, по которым проще не получится: http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/276994

Comment: @Qwertiy: А это в качестве вопроса о принципиальной возможности: https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выстраивать DOM в памяти - вещь достаточно дорогостоящая.

Если речь идёт о конкретной странице, из которой надо достать небольшой кусок данных, я бы использовал регулярные выражения (естественно, если речь не идёт о скрипте, выполняемом на этой странице).

Но вообще, правильным и, вероятно, оптимальным решением будет использовать потоковый html-парсер, который не станет строить dom в памяти, а позволит немедленно поэлементно обрабатывать данные.

Comment: Уверены, что потоковый парсер на самом деле не строит DOM в памяти?

Comment: @avp, я именно о dom-дереве. Это как XmlReader vs XmlDocument. Хотя, конечно, зависит от парсера. Но за dom-дерево в памяти потокового парсера хочется поотрывать руки :)

Comment: Т.е. Вы считаете, что обработчику верхнего уровня иерархии объектов содержимое нижних уровней должно быть недоступно? Только сведение о том, что уровень успешно разобран.

Comment: @avp, нету уровней, на то он и потоковый. Есть только поток элементов - как у XmlReader'а.

Comment: Ну, сами уровни (хотя бы имена тегов в текущей иерерхии) должны быть. Иначе, получив данные элемента, мы просто не знали бы к чему эти данные относятся.

Answer (score 0):

Если из определенной - тест все расставит по местам.

Культура работы с XML-образными данными обязывает для парсинга HTML задействовать DOM.

Comment: Структура одинаковая,текст меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от конкретных реализаций парсера HTML(XML), и автомата в regex. Поэтому однозначного ответа быть не может, поможет только тестирование.
Но обычно regex не рекомендуют использовать для работы с XML/HTML.